# Apache ignite cache expiry

Tags: python, ignite, cache-expiration

I am using Apache Ignite in my python project. I am using 'pyignite' client to make a connection.
I need to set some expiry time for cache. Also, need to configure system resources for apache ignite. If anyone knows the configuration help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set expiry in your [Ignite XML configuration](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/expiry-policies) when starting your server nodes:

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
    ...

    <property name="expiryPolicyFactory">
        <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.CreatedExpiryPolicy" factory-method="factoryOf">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.Duration">
                    <constructor-arg value="MINUTES"/>
                    <constructor-arg value="5"/>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

System resources are configured by adjusting [data region size](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/memory-configuration) and [thread pools size](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/thread-pools).

Comment: Thanks, @alamar.

Comment: I don't see a cache name mentioned in the expiry configuration. Does it work for all cache?

Comment: It's in the bean CacheConfiguration which describes one (named) cache. You can also use cache groups to configure multiple similar caches.